# Laravel-8 . 404 error page on delete a post

Tags: routes, http-status-code-404, laravel-8

I am using

inside web.php:

```
Route::post('/delete',[PostController::class,'destroy'])->name('post.delete');
```

&&

inside blade template:

```html
<form   method="POST" class="d-inline" action="{{route('post.delete')}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="slug" value="{{ $post->slug }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn px-0 d-inline">Delete</button>
</form>
```

The problem is: when I click on the delete button the 404 exception is throw

Github repository: https://github.com/Khokon-Chandra/Blog-Backend.git

Comment: Aren't you missing the route model binding there???

Answer (score 1):

Try to using :

```
Route:delete('/delete',[PostController::class,'destroy'])
```

and add

```
@method('delete')
```

inside your blade after `@csrf`